# Merge specific text files

Tags: matlab, loops, file, merge

I have a problem in my code. I am using some loops in order to create mulptile .txt files with specific names, eg mR1.txt, mR2.txt,...mR100.txt. After that I merge them into one file with the following commands:

```
name=regexp(fileread('names.txt'), '\r?\n', 'split') .';
file1=regexp(fileread('data.txt'), '\r?\n', 'split') .';
.....
    
for n=1:numel(name);
    for z=1:size(file1)
    ........ %making caluclations
        
    FP=fopen(sprintf('mR%g0.txt',z),'wt');
    fprintf(FP,'%s\t',file1{z},num2str(number),num2str(number);  
    fclose(FP);
    
    txtFiles = dir('mR*.txt') ;  % get the text files in the present folder 
    N = length(txtFiles) ;      % Total number of text files 
    iwant = cell(N,1) ;         % initlaize the data required 
    % loop for each file 
    for i = 1:N
    thisFile = txtFiles(i).name ;
    iwant{i} = importdata(thisFile) ;  % read data of the text file 
    end
    iwant = cell2mat(iwant) ;
    
    outFile = strcat('finalR',num2str(n),'.txt') ;  
    dlmwrite(outFile,iwant,'delimiter','\t')
   
    end
end
```

I would like to create for each iteration M1_mR1.txt,...,M1_mr100.txt, and M1_mR1.txt,..., M2_mR100.txt. After that I would like to merge all the files that Have prefix M1_.....txt into one file and all the files that Have prefix M2_.....txt into one file.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in multiple ways.
Note about sorting: The default sorting in files will give higher value to file2 than file100, so you need to sort by actual number value. This is done by converting the filename numbers to first code and second code, and then sort by the second code with `sortrows`.

So this will solve the problem:

```
clear
textfiles_dir=dir('M*_mR*.txt');
textfiles_name={textfiles_dir.name}; %group the filenames into cell array
textfiles_codes=cellfun(@(fname)textscan(fname,'M%d_mR%d.txt'),textfiles_name,'Uniform',false);
textfiles_codes=cell2mat(cat(1,textfiles_codes{:})); %separate bw first and second code
disp(textfiles_codes)

[sorted_codes,orig_idx]=sortrows(textfiles_codes,2); %sort by second code
first_codes=sorted_codes(:,1);
second_codes=sorted_codes(:,2);
unique_firstcodes=unique(first_codes);


for ifirstcode=1:length(unique_firstcodes)
    firstcode=unique_firstcodes(ifirstcode);
    fprintf('firstcode=%d: ',firstcode)
    target_name=sprintf('Merged%d.txt',firstcode);
    f_target=fopen(target_name,'w');
    idxs=orig_idx(first_codes==firstcode); % already sorted in increasing order
    for i=1:length(idxs)
        idx=idxs(i);
        fname=textfiles_name{idx};
        fprintf(' %s ',fname)
        f_src=fopen(fname,'r');
        src_text=fread(f_src,'*char')';
        fclose(f_src);
        fwrite( f_target,src_text);
    end
    fclose(f_target);
    fprintf('\n')
end
fprintf('Done!\n')
```

Comment: Excuse me , but I run this code in MATLAB and I do not take the Merged files I want.. Could you help me?